Find all differences between groups in polars dataframe
I have one polars dataframe and I am trying to find the differences (fields that have their values changed) on multiple columns between groups on one key. There can be multiple groups in the dataframe and more than one column. The groups is essentially a datetime in int format (YYYYMMDD)
How can I find the rows where there is a new value of (any) column on a date?
Sample Data:
raw_df = pl.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'AAPL','update_time': 20241112,'status':'trading', 'underlying': 'y'},
    {'id': 'MSFT','update_time': 20241113,'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'x'},
    {'id': 'NVDA','update_time': 20241112,'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'z'},
    {'id': 'MSFT','update_time': 20241112,'status': 'pending','underlying': 'x'},
    {'id': 'AAPL','update_time': 20241113,'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'y'},
    {'id': 'NVDA','update_time': 20241113,'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'z'},
    {'id': 'TSLA','update_time': 20241112,'status': 'closed', 'underlying': 'v'},
    ]
)

expected_df = pl.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'MSFT','update_time': 20241112,'status':'pending', 'underlying': 'x'},
    {'id': 'MSFT','update_time': 20241113,'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'x'},
    ]
)


Below is what the data input looks like.
shape: (7, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  ┆ underlying │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ AAPL ┆ 20241112    ┆ trading ┆ y          │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ x          │
│ NVDA ┆ 20241112    ┆ trading ┆ z          │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending ┆ x          │
│ AAPL ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ y          │
│ NVDA ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ z          │
│ TSLA ┆ 20241112    ┆ closed  ┆ v          │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘

And the expected result below, showing the id the update time and the field that has changed. If there are more than 1 field changed/updated, ideally it should go into a new row.
I am trying to find the fields that have changed, grouped by 'update_time' on the key 'id'. One caveat is that there can be ids' that are present in a group but not in another group for example 'TSLA'. Hence, these ids that are not common or the intersection between groups can be ignored. Since only MSFT has the status changed, it should be filtered to those two rows where it has been updated. The field changes should only be done on all other columns except update_time which is what we are using to group by.
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────┴

Could not figure out how to do this, but this is the closest i have, which could not work on the caveat mentioned earlier.
def find_updated_field_differences(df):
        columns_to_check = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'id' and col != 'update_time']

        sorted_df = df.sort('update_time')
        grouped_df = sorted_df.groupby(["update_time"])
        
        result_data = []
        
        for group_key, group_df in grouped_df:
            print(group_df)
    
            for col in columns_to_check:

                group_df = group_df.with_columns(
                    (pl.col(col) != pl.col(col).shift()).alias(f"{col}_changed")
                )
            
            differing_rows = group_df.filter(
                pl.any([pl.col(f"{col}_changed") for col in columns_to_check])
            )


            result_data.append(differing_rows)
        
        differing_df = pl.concat(result_data)
        
        differing_df = differing_df.sort("id")
        
        return differing_df


To me, the question is not entirely clear. What is the expected outcome if a column changes back and forth between two-values (same id, different dates)? Do we expect all rows to be kept or just two rows with the two unique values?

@Hericks Thanks for spotting that, it should be compared on every two groups. Comparing from the previous date. Hence, will expect to see a new row on MSFT 20241114 and pending (if these two are the changes).
Only the rows where there are unique updates/changes should be kept. Thanks again

Your approach is slightly over-complicating things. What I suggest is that you first sort the data by id and update_time, then shift the data to prepare for comaparison. After that, you can identify the rows where id is the same but where there is a difference:
import polars as pl

def find_updated_field_differences(df):
    sorted_df = df.sort(['id', 'update_time'])
    
    shifted_df = sorted_df.shift(-1)

    mask = (
        (sorted_df['id'] == shifted_df['id']) &
        ((sorted_df['status'] != shifted_df['status']) | (sorted_df['underlying'] != shifted_df['underlying']))
    )

    start_changes = sorted_df.filter(mask)
    end_changes = sorted_df.shift(-1).filter(mask)
    differing_df = pl.concat([start_changes, end_changes]).unique()

    return differing_df.sort(['id', 'update_time'])

raw_df = pl.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'AAPL', 'update_time': 20241112, 'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'y'},
    {'id': 'MSFT', 'update_time': 20241113, 'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'x'},
    {'id': 'NVDA', 'update_time': 20241112, 'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'z'},
    {'id': 'MSFT', 'update_time': 20241112, 'status': 'pending', 'underlying': 'x'},
    {'id': 'AAPL', 'update_time': 20241113, 'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'y'},
    {'id': 'NVDA', 'update_time': 20241113, 'status': 'trading', 'underlying': 'z'},
    {'id': 'TSLA', 'update_time': 20241112, 'status': 'closed', 'underlying': 'v'},
])

result_df = find_updated_field_differences(raw_df)
print(result_df)

which gives you
shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  ┆ underlying │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending ┆ x          │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ x          │


Polars has a dedicated function to simplify the col != col.shift() check.
Run-length encoding: .rle_id()
df.with_columns(
   pl.exclude("id", "update_time").rle_id().over("id").name.suffix("_change")
)

shape: (7, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  ┆ underlying ┆ status_change ┆ underlying_change │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---               │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     ┆ str        ┆ u32           ┆ u32               │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ AAPL ┆ 20241112    ┆ trading ┆ y          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ x          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
│ NVDA ┆ 20241112    ┆ trading ┆ z          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending ┆ x          ┆ 1             ┆ 0                 │
│ AAPL ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ y          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
│ NVDA ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ z          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
│ TSLA ┆ 20241112    ┆ closed  ┆ v          ┆ 0             ┆ 0                 │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────┘

Not sure if I'm over-simplifying things or not - but in the example case it seems like you just want to check if any columns contain a change.
i.e. rle_id > 0
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(
      (pl.exclude("id", "update_time").rle_id() > 0).any().over("id")
   ) 
)

shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  ┆ underlying │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ x          │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending ┆ x          │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘


Thanks, this is the most elegant solution yet. But its weird that i'm having an irreproducible error that shows "thread '' panicked at 'assertion failed: (left == right)" lhs and rhs must have the same length', D:\bld\polars_1690884875212_build_env.cargo\git\checkouts\arrow2-8a2ad61d97265680\d5c78e7\src\compute\boolean_kleene.rs:24:5
Seems like an internal bug, am not too familiar with Rust. This error (or not) happens occasionally on the same schema, so am puzzled. Nonetheless, this solutions works on the simplified data.

Definitely an internal bug - i'll see if I can reproduce it on a larger example.

I have been unable to reproduce on 0.20.22-rc.1 - if you manage to make a reproducible example please file a bug. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/

In general, it sounds like you'd like to keep all unique rows (ignoring update_time) in a group defined by id if the corresponding group has at least two unique rows (i.e. there was a change).
This can be achieved as follows.
(
    raw_df
    .sort("update_time")
    .unique(subset=["id", "status", "underlying"], keep="first", maintain_order=True)
    .filter(
        pl.len().over("id") > 1
    )
)

shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ id   ┆ update_time ┆ status  ┆ underlying │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ i64         ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ MSFT ┆ 20241112    ┆ pending ┆ x          │
│ MSFT ┆ 20241113    ┆ trading ┆ x          │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘


pl.DataFrame.unique drops duplicate rows. The subset parameter specifies, which columns to consider when comparing two rows as possible duplicates.
pl.len().over("id") counts the number of unique rows in each group defined by id.

Sorting by update_time and setting the parameters keep="first", maintain_order=True in the call to pl.DataFrame.unique is optional. I use it to ensure that the first (in time) occurrence of each unique row (per group defined by id) is kept.
